# Can you make an attribute not trigger resource change?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In Terraform, is there a way of setting an attribute so that it does not trigger the resource to update?

Example:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "sometimes_changes" {
  ...

  # label the function with timestamp - don't let this trigger an update.

  labels = {
    timestamp = timestamp
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`ignore_changes` block:](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes)

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "sometimes_changes" {

...
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [
          labels,
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha. That's close but not exactly what I want. `ignore_changes` causes the field to be completely ignored for purposes of resource _updates_. Desired behaviour is that the attribute is ignored _only_ when no other attributes are updated.

Comment: The advanced behavior (ignored but managed) is not supported natively : https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/possible-to-ignore-changes-but-still-manage/38842